# Returning to 'main menu' for mini email program

Tags: python

So for practice, I tried writing a simple program to read/write emails from the terminal/python shell. My problem is that whenever I try entering an invalid response, it ends the program rather than returning to the 'main menu,' so to speak. Same problem for when I try to give the option of quitting the program and asking the user to confirm that they want to exit. This is my code:

```
import smtplib
import imaplib
import email

print 'Welcome to NhuMail'
print '\n \nPlease enter your login information: \n'
user = raw_input('Email User:')
pw = raw_input("Password:")


def check_mail(user, pw):
    # Login to INBOX
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
    imap.login(user, pw)
    imap.select('INBOX')

    # Use search(), not status()
    status, response = imap.search('INBOX', '(UNSEEN)')
    unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()

    # Print the count of all unread messages
    print '\n\nYou have %s unread messages.' % (len(unread_msg_nums))

def read_mail():
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com", 993)
    imap.login(user, pw)
    imap.list()
    imap.select("inbox")
    status, response = imap.search('INBOX', '(UNSEEN)')
    unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()
    result, data = imap.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search and return uids instead
    latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
    result, data = imap.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = data[0][1]


    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)

    print email_message['To']

    print email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['From']) # for parsing "Yuji Tomita" <yuji@grovemade.com>

    email_items = email_message.items()
    # print all headers
    print email_items[1]
    print email_items[2]
    print email_items[5]
    print '\n'



    b = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
    if b.is_multipart():
        for payload in b.get_payload():
            # if payload.is_multipart(): ...
            print payload.get_payload()
        else:
            print b.get_payload()

def new_mail():
    from_add = user
    to_add = raw_input('Enter TO address:')
    msg = raw_input('Enter desired message:')


    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user,pw)
    server.sendmail(from_add,to_add,msg)

def exit_mail():
    confirm_exit = raw_input('Are you sure you want to exit? (Yes/No):')
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    if confirm_exit == 'Yes':
        server.quit()
        print 'Nice Nhu-ing you! Come again soon :)'
    elif confirm_exit == 'No':
        return prompt


def mail_options():
    prompt = raw_input('Say \'Nhu\' to compose a message \nOR \nSay \'Read\' to read unread message \nOR \nSay \'Escape\' to exit NhuMail: \n')

    while True:
        if prompt == 'Nhu':
            new_mail()
            return prompt

        elif prompt == 'Read':
            read_mail()
            return prompt

        elif prompt == 'Escape':
            exit_mail()
            break

        else:
            print 'You didn\'t enter one of the options!'
            return prompt


check_mail(user,pw)
mail_options()
```

Comment: Of course the program ends; the last line of your code is `mail_options()`. When it returns, the program ends. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Do you ever get a traceback or error?

Comment: However, there appears to be an infinite loop in `mail_options()`. But then, you can only use it once and then it "freezes", because there is no additional prompts.

Comment: After you execute mail_options() for any of them you just return what they typed in. You don't ask them again. I'll write an naswer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep calling `mail_options()`. You can do this with an infinite loop:

```
while True:
    mail_options()
```

You could also put the loop inside `mail_options()`:

```
def mail_options():
    while True:
        prompt = raw_input('Say \'Nhu\' to compose a message \nOR \nSay \'Read\' to read unread message \nOR \nSay \'Escape\' to exit NhuMail: \n')
            while True:
                if prompt == 'Nhu':
                    new_mail()

                elif prompt == 'Read':
                    read_mail()

                elif prompt == 'Escape':
                    exit_mail()
                    break

                else:
                    print 'You didn\'t enter one of the options!'
```

Comment: Beat me by a single second!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your program lies in `mail_options()`. You have an infinite loop, that can only run a single time, and then exits every time time due to the use of a `return` statement. Make an infinite loop to continuously show `mail_options()`, and it should fix your issue. You're only calling it once, which is why it exits.

You can do:

```
while True:
    mail_options()
```

Another option would be asking the prompt inside the loop, and ridding the function of return statements.

```
def mail_options():
    while True:
        prompt = raw_input('Say \'Nhu\' to compose a message \nOR \nSay \'Read\' to read unread message \nOR \nSay \'Escape\' to exit NhuMail: \n')
        if prompt == 'Nhu':
            new_mail()

        elif prompt == 'Read':
            read_mail()

        elif prompt == 'Escape':
            exit_mail()
            return # Get out of the function.

        else:
            print 'You didn\'t enter one of the options!'
```

Comment: What about his only calling it once?

Comment: There was a `return` statement. So of course, call it once, means only doing one thing.

Comment: I know *that* he's only calling it one. You said, "[his] only calling it once", though, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oh, that's a typo. Time to fix!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your mail_options() to this:

```
def mail_options():
    while True:
        prompt = raw_input('Say \'Nhu\' to compose a message \nOR \nSay \'Read\' to read unread message \nOR \nSay \'Escape\' to exit NhuMail: \n')
        if prompt == 'Nhu':
            new_mail()

        elif prompt == 'Read':
            read_mail()

        elif prompt == 'Escape':
            exit_mail()
            break

        else:
            print 'You didn\'t enter one of the options!'
```

You present the prompt once and then as soon as you get their result, you return what they said after running the specified function, and then because you use a `return` keyword, it breaks out of the loop and function and exits the program.

Comment: How is this different from my answer, except the lack of an explanation?

Comment: I was in the process of writing it when you posted yours and I didn't see... Plus, you didn't get rid of the return statements, they would still break out of the loop and script (unless you did your first option), but the first one is kind of messy, IMO